# AngularJS: start watching for form change after form is compiled

Tags: angularjs, forms, watch

I wish to watch if the form is pristine. My HTML looks like this:

```
 <div ng-if="ObservationCtrl.showHeader">
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="ObservationCtrl.observationForm" role="form" ng-if="!ObservationCtrl.doingResolve">
  {{ObservationCtrl.observationForm.$pristine}}
       <!-- SOME HTML -->
    </form>
 </div>
```

In my controller, I have following code:

```
    console.log(self.observationForm);

    $timeout(function(){
            $scope.$watch('self.observationForm', function() {
                if(self.observationForm) { 
                    console.log('form is valid? ', self.observationForm.$pristine); 
                } else {
                    console.log('form is not defined');
                }

            });
        },2000);
```

This logs `undefined`, but does the trick, since it starts watching form after 2 sec, when it already exists. However if I decrease the timeout to etc. 100, or even 0, then I get `form is not defined` message and when I change something in the form, the change is not recognized. According to some SO posts, that is because I start watching the form *before* it is compiled.

I wish to start watching the form after it is compiled. Relying on some predefined timeout is tricky, but I haven't found any other way to do that. I have also tried `$evalAsync`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The `$scope` does not know of the `self` property, you should change it to the "controller as" name. Also, you say you watch the `$pristine` property, so you should watch that one:

```
$scope.$watch('ObservationCtrl.observationForm.$pristine}', function(val) {
    console.log("Is pristine:", val);
});
```

Or you can change it to a function callback:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return self.observationForm.$pristine;
}, function(val) {
    console.log("Is pristine:", val);
});
```

You can of course do checks if the form already exists, which in your case is because of the `ng-if` directive:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    if (self.observationForm) {
        return self.observationForm.$pristine;
    }

    return false;
}, function(val) {
    console.log("Is pristine:", val);
});
```

Comment: great! just a small typo - there should not be a curly bracket after `$pristine`. thanks a lot